# Regex to match a valid hex string but not all '0'

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to write a `Regex` to match a valid Hex string but without all zero values.

How to write a `Regex` to match valid hex string is a common knowledge.

The simplest is `^0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+$`.

But, among all the possible hex strings, the ones match Zero should be invalid.

e.g.,

`0x0`, `0x00`, `0x00000` are all invalid

but

`0x01`, `0x001`, `0x010` are valid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a lookahead to restrict the match:

```
^0[xX](?!0+$)[0-9a-fA-F]+$
      ^^^^^^^
```

Here, after matching `0x` or `0X`, the `(?!0+)` negative lookahead fails the match if there are 1+ zeros to the end of the string immediately to the right.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1PuOiC/1)

C# possible usage example:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^0x(?!0+$)[0-9a-f]+$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
{
    // Valid
}
```

Comment: Do you know of a good tutorial about lookahead/behind - i kept failing understanding these features

Comment: @NirMH I think [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) is great.

Comment: @NirMH If my solution works for you please consider accepting the answer.